# How can I compile raspberry2 drivers?

Tags: archlinux, software-compilation

I downloaded raspberry2 drivers from [github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland). When I typed `./buildme`
I get

```
./buildme: line 3: arch: command not found
./buildme: line 3: [: armv6l: unary operator expected
./buildme: line 3: arch: command not found
./buildme: line 3: [: armv7l: unary operator expected
~/Desktop/userland-master/build/arm-linux/release ~/Desktop/userland-master
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
```

error. How can I compile these drivers?

My system is [Arch Linux Arm](http://archlinuxarm.org/) : `Linux alarmpi 4.1.6-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 22 12:18:37 MDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: Where are you compiling this on the Pi or your PC? Did you install the cross compile toolchain?

Comment: I am compiling on Pi

Comment: It appears from the readme page for the github project that it requires cmake and a cross compile toolchain. This strongly implies that it is not setup to compile on the Pi but your PC. If compiled on the Pi there would be no need for a cross compile toolchain.